# Download file from FTP based on extensions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, wildcard

Have used the following link for monitoring an FTP folder and downloading files from it:
https://jhonatantirado.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/download-and-delete-files-from-ftp-using-powershell/

I need to download only `.xml` files.

I am very new to PowerShell, anything simple that I am missing?

```
if ($line -ne ''| $_.extension -eq '.bpxml-2014' -or $_.extension -eq '.xml') 
{ 
}
```

The `$line` has my filename with extension. How do I check if it has the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Windows includes a command line FTP client. It can be run with a command script. Use the `-s` switch to specify the script file.

A command like `mget *.xml` ought to be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if ($line -Like "*.xml" -or $line -Like ".bpxml-2014")
{
    ...
}
```

See [PowerShell Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators).

For a full example, see [Download files whose name contains a specific string from an FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64754385/850848).

---

Alternatively see *(my)* solution using WinSCP .NET assembly used from a PowerShell script:
[Listing files matching wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_listing_files_matching_wildcard)

And just download the matching files using the [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles).